# Storage encryption on Linux desktop: LVM on LUKS or ZFS

Tags: lvm, luks, zfs, disk-encryption

I choose solution for storage encryption on Linux desktop. For years LVM on LUKS was a best option with superior performance and reliability. But ZFS on Linux actively develops new functions and now we have options.

I compared LVM on LUKS and ZFS with various fio tests with default encryption settings, provided by developers and mantainers: aes-xts-512b at LUKS, aes-256-gcm at ZFS. Here are average bandwidth and latency metrics at RAM block device for each volume type:

[image: Bandwidth][image: Latency]

At the first comparsion on the charts looks controversional. XTS obviously faster than GTC on random small blocks. But on sequentional reads and writes ZFS shows comparable latency with a noticeable increase in bandwidth!

Which of these solutions is best suited for desktop tasks in terms of performance?
Now I find it difficult to choose and I will be grateful for the advices.

**UPD1**:

For example, my typical storage tasks are:

- Web browser loads: mixed reads & writes files near 100-1000 KB in local cache;
- Starting applications: random reads system binaries near 100-1000 KB;
- Compiling software: reads & writes hudge amount of small files;
- Storing archive like photos: mostly writes files up to 10 MB, rare reads;
- Serving huge files like UHD videos for home media: up to 100 GB sequetial writes or reads;
- And more.

It is easy to optimize system for each individual task. But which of the solutions best fit all of them?

**UPD2**:

And here is some real life measurements with files: [image: Tar operations time]

Comment: clear upvote for this excellent work on doing your own benchmarking! I'm really not an expert on this, but what is the desktop tasks where you think or know that storage is a limiting factor? I ask because I, for example, compile lots of software, so that might be different from the desktop tasks of someone waiting a lot to start large desktop software (say, Libreoffice, autoCAD, browsers), might be different from someone playing modern games, might be different from someone doing video editing!

Comment: You marked it well! But unlike any enterprise one purpose system with determined I/O profile, desktop should handle any type of load well, because it can do anything at different times.

This makes my choice difficult. It seems that the most universal solution with the best performance in most scenarios is required.

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt big UHD videos?

Comment: I don't. It's not a security requirement, but with LUKS whole device encryption this comes naturally. Before the measurements I thought there was a zero overhead.

Answer (score 2):

And between LUKS and ZFS encryption I chose fscrypt at ext4.

Fscrypt offers slightly weaker protection in some points:

- It's exposures files metadata: fact of existing, size, files count in directory.
- It cannot be used for whole root encryption: sensitive data may leak in system logs or file indexes. Swap encryption requires extra and extra steps.
- In some configurations its encryption may depends on weak hash of [system's password](https://github.com/google/fscrypt#securing-your-login-passphrase) in shadow. But modern distributions are replacing sha512 with more secure (fixme) yescrypt algorithm for that purpose.

On the other hand fscrypt provides aes-256-xts encryption for data and aes-256-cts for filenames with near line encryption speeds:
[image]

If fscrypt limitations fit yours threats model it is the best solution in terms of throughput and latency.